# Templating over algebraic operators

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to write 4 big C++ methods that differ only from a simple operator (+, -, *, /) that occurs on some definite places within the definitions.

Instead of writing 4 methods, I would like to have a single block of code to illustrate that the methods have fundamentally the same logic with only the operator differing. It would also be easier to fix or improve the logic.

I also would like to make the methods run fast (as they are used intensively) by being compiled distinctly like it is the case with template functions. So, I am not satisfied with the idea of adding a lambda function parameter representing the operator to a single method (or a category parameter tested  whenever the choice of the operator occurs.)

Is there some way to achieve what I want with a method having template arguments ? Maybe, it is possible to somewhat translate operators to different types to match the template logic ?

For your information, I use C++14.

Comment: The lambda is what you want, they don't magically make your code slow (just make sure to pass it as a parameter of a templated type, rather than a function pointer or `std::function`, if you want it to be baked into the assembly). You can also use `std::plus` and others instead of handwritten lambdas, they do the same thing.

Comment: you mean different lambdas are considered to have different types (even if they take the same types of arguments and return value) so the compilation will "bake" a specific code block for each lambda ?

Comment: Yep, assuming you pass them as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas and function templates are the most idiomatic solution:

```cpp
template <typename F>
int foo(F op, int x, int y) {
    return op(x, y);
}

int main() {
    auto plus = [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
    return foo(plus, 1, 2);
}
```

This compiles to (https://godbolt.org/z/oa5b8xj55):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

Lambdas don't slow down your code in this case because each lambda has a distinct type and `op(...)` can be easily inlined.

Specifically, in a specialization of `foo` such as `foo<__lambda>(__lambda, int, int)`, `op(...)` translates to calling `__lambda::operator()(int, int) const`. Since the definition of the call operator is visible and the lambda has no captures, optimization is easy.

A lot of functions in the `<algorithm>` header have the same design.

Comment: You dont need to define `plus`, there's `std::plus` et.al.